# What happens when my go.mod version is newer than the golang version of the container image im using?

Tags: go, devops

I've got a pipeline that runs "go build" in one of the jobs. The go.mod file in our project contains "go 1.18" but the container the "go build" is being executed in is using a golang 1.17 image. I'm curious what happens in this scenario? The build works fine but I'm curious if it's actually compiling to go 1.18 or is it only compiling to 1.17 and just not giving a warning or making it obvious there's a mismatch between go.mod and the container image version? What, if any, problems would be caused by mismatching the container image version and the go.mod version?

I'm not even sure what to try or what to be looking for here. Several developer peers didn't know the answer but were interested in what i find out, and google didn't help either.

Comment: You can only compile with the version of `go` which are calling. It is not going to somehow get a newer compiler for you. The module may require functionality from a newer version of go, so it may not build at all. The compiler cannot tell what features may be missing from future versions, so it will attempt to build the package regardless.

Comment: What @JimB said. Also since the go language guarantees backward compatibility, compiling with the latest go version is highly recommended. It gives you all the latest security updates (TLS issues etc) - so you should update your pipeline's build version accordingly.